# Can't access files in ROOT webapp

Tags: java, html, jsp, tomcat6

I have got a ROOT application on my tomcat application server. When I add files to the ROOT folder I can't access them. I had files in the folder before which were named help.html and index.html and they seem to work fine. Any new files which I create, I get 404 error when trying to access them. The permissions are the same. Any clues why ?

Comment: does it work if you restart tomcat? (i.e. will it pick up the files at next restart of tomcat)

Comment: Which version of tomcat?  Have you changed it recently?

Comment: No it doesn't work with the re-start. The version of tomcat is 6.0.24. All the other files work in there. It's just with the new files.

Comment: is your root in server.xml same as before? docbase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are they *.html files as well? Have they the same owner and permissions as the rest of the files?

Comment: Found the issue. There were some issue with the ROOT webapp and after I installed the app again it worked...